# Sum this Finite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

The sequence $x_n$ is defined by $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + x_n$. Suppose S = $$\sum_{i=1}^{99} {1\over x_i+1}$$
If $x_1 = {1\over 60}$ , find $[S]$ (where $[x]$ represents integral part of $x$)

MY WORK :-
Well basically we see that $x_{n+1} = x_n (x_n+1)$ thus we get that ${x_{n+1}\over x_n} = x_n+1$.
Thus ${1\over x_n+1} = {x_n\over x_{n+1}}$. So basically the series sums up to ${x_1\over x_2}+{x_2\over x_3}+{x_3\over x_4}+\cdots + {x_{n-1}\over x_n}+{x_n\over x_{n+1}}$. But this is where i am stuck; what to do now; how to simplify ??

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2365000p19286232, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h517503p2911708. The first step is to note that $\frac 1{x_n+1}=\frac 1{x_n}-\frac 1{x_{n+1}}$ so that you get a telescoping sum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{a_n+1}$ with $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n+1)$ and $a_1=\frac12$ have a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081033/does-sum-infty-n-1-frac1a-n1-with-a-n1-a-na-n1-and-a-1-f)